# How to launch Windows Terminal from command without invoking wt.exe alias?

Tags: windows-11, windows-terminal

On my computer, UWP apps Paint and Windows Terminal sometimes won't launch when invoked by their aliases. Launching `mspaint.exe` will cause an application error event involving `mspaint.exe` on module `KERNELBASE.dll`. Launching `wt.exe` will cause an error involving `WindowsTerminal.exe` on module `ucrtbase.dll`. Whenever this happens, I have to restart the computer to fix the issue.

I can avoid using mspaint.exe on file association by replacing the entire registry subkey `HKCR\SystemFileAssociations\image\shell\edit` with Paint App's own Appx registry entry `HKCR\AppXcesbfs704v2mjbts9dkr42s9vmrhxbkj\shell\open`. But I cannot find an `HKCR\Appx*` subkey for Windows Terminal, persumably because Windows Terminal doesn't have any file association. In this case how can I open Terminal from command line without using "wt.exe" alias? The "Open in Terminal" context menu entry as well as "Terminal" and "Terminal (Admin)" in Win+X context menu can still open Windows Terminal properly.

My goal here is to fix the command so that context menu entries `HKCR\Directory\Background\shell\PowerShellWAdmin` (Open terminal here as admin, current command `powershell.exe -Command "Start-Process wt.exe -ArgumentList -p ""%V""" -Verb RunAs`) and `HKCR\Directory\Background\shell\WSL` (Open in WSL profile, current command `wt.exe -p "Ubuntu" -d "%V"`) can open Windows Terminal reliably.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to fix the corruption in Windows? See [Repair Install Windows 11 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/repair-install-windows-11-with-an-in-place-upgrade.418/).

Comment: In-place upgrade or sfc /scannow won't fix the issue.

Comment: If you tried and it didn't help, it might perhaps be better to post a separate question about the errors you're getting, with screenshots.

Comment: Definitely agree with @harrymc.  This looks to be an [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Happy to try to answer the actual question being asked here, but I'm not sure that my answer is going to help you solve your actual problem.

Comment: Your login registry profile is screwed. Create a new admin user and move your stuff over to the new login. Your programs will still be installed but you may have to locate the shortcuts again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> UWP apps Paint and Windows Terminal sometimes won't launch when invoked by their aliases.

A few things to try real fast to see if you can determine your root problem ...

First, open *Manage app execution aliases* in the Windows *Settings*.  Is there a chance that there are two or more entries for `wt.exe` or `paint.exe` there?  For `wt.exe`, it might be listed under:

- Terminal
- Terminal Preview
- Windows Terminal
- Windows Terminal Preview

I'm wondering if maybe the currently active alias is getting set to an older, perhaps removed version.  Toggling that older execution alias off *might* allow you to solve the problem without rebooting.

If there's just a single alias for those apps, then perhaps just toggling them off and back on again will work.  Or perhaps they've just been set to *Off* for some reason, and toggling them to *On* will solve it.

> how can I open Terminal from command line without using `wt.exe` alias? ...
>
> My goal here is to fix the command so that context menu entries

On my system, from PowerShell, I can launch via:

```
& 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_1.15.2713.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\WindowsTerminal.exe' -p "Ubuntu-22.04"
# or
& 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_1.15.2713.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\wt.exe' -p "Ubuntu-22.04"
```

If that path doesn't work for you, find the correct one with:

```
(Get-AppxPackage |? { $_.Name -like "*Term*" }).InstallLocation
```

Note that you can also launch a Store app from the command-line if you know its `PackageFamilyName` and ID. For Terminal, that would be:

```
explorer.exe shell:appsFolder\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App
```

However, that mechanism won't allow you to pass in arguments.

Comment: Launching it directly still won't start Windows Terminal / Paint properly (same error message). I guess there was something wrong when updating 22000 to 22621 since reverting to 22000 Build will solve the issue. I guess I will stuck with 22000 for a while.

Comment: @user167420 Bummer - I had a feeling that wasn't going to be the solution to the root issue, but it was worth a try.